# Frame-Relay Direct Serial, can't ping

Tags: troubleshooting

I am working on my packet tracer lab. I have a bit long or series of questions but may be short answers can solve my problem. I am using 3 routers. all connected to each other using serial cable.
R1 and R2 are using "Encap PPP" and works fine with OSPF, R2 and R3 are connected using frame-relay. Both serial interfaces are up but can't ping each other. As R3 is ISP Router can't use any routing protocol, have to use IP route back to internal network. If I use FR cloud everything start working but as per requirement I have to use serial direct connection.

1. What could be possible solution for frame relay to work with direct serial connection..
2. For "IP Route" do I have to have classful subnet mask or have to use according to internal network. internal network is 192.168.2.0/25 do ihave to use "ip route 192.168.2.0 0.0.127.255" or "ip route 192.168.0.0 0.0.0.255" or can it be used either way. what is best option?
3. Ask me I feel there will be some information missing to get to right solution. I will provide as much as I can.

Regards
Ahmed

Answer (score 1):

I don't work with Cisco devices very often and it's been ages since I've worked with frame-relay but this might help. I think you need to disable keepalive and you need to configure one side as the clock source when you're setting up an "emulated" frame-relay connection. You would do the same thing with setting up a `frame-relay back-to-back` connection between two routers at home, for instance. Take what you need from the following configs and see if it works for you:

---

**ROUTER1**

interface Serial0

no ip address

encapsulation frame-relay

no keepalive

no fair-queue

service-module 56k clock source internal

no service-module 56k remote-loopback

!

interface Serial0.1 point-to-point

ip address 10.0.0.1 255.0.0.0

frame-relay interface-dlci 100

---

**ROUTER2**

interface Serial0

no ip address

encapsulation frame-relay

no keepalive

no fair-queue

no service-module 56k remote-loopback

!

interface Serial0.1 point-to-point

ip address 10.0.0.2 255.0.0.0

frame-relay interface-dlci 100

Comment: **R2**

 - int serial 0/0/1
 - description xxx
 - ip addres 70.14.1.13 255.255.255.252
 - encap frame-relay frame-relay map ip 70.14.1.14 100 broadcast cisco 
 - no shut down 
 - exit

**R3**

- int serial 0/0/1
- description xxx
- ip addres 70.14.1.13 255.255.255.252
- encap frame-relay
- frame-relay map ip 70.14.1.14 100 broadcast cisco 
- clock rate 64000
- no shut down
- exit

@joeqwerty I have used these command whatelse can be added.

Comment: did you disable keepalive? I'm pretty sure that with an `emulated` circuit there won't be any LMI (because there's no frame-relay switch) so you have to set `no keepalive`.

Comment: Yes, i did use "no keepalive" to make it working, i used same DLCI in above mentioned comment but infact i was using 100 for R2 and 200 for R3, so i had to change and keep DLCI same on both ends, which i couldn't understand why?

Comment: The DLCI needs to be the same on both sides. That is the connection identifier. Both sides need to use the same connection identifier. - So is it working now?